# How to create a full project on drupal.org?

Tags: community-official-site

I have created a custom module in Drupal 7. And now I want to contribute this module via [drupal.org](https://www.drupal.org/). For this I have created my account on drupal.org and [created a sandbox project](https://www.drupal.org/create-sandbox).

Now I am not getting how to make it full project.

Answer (score 3):

For promoting the sandbox module to full project requires for going through a one time review process.

Check:
[Apply for permission to create full projects](https://www.drupal.org/node/1011698)

Before creating an issue for the promotion, make sure you go through the [project application checklist](https://www.drupal.org/node/1587704) to get good reviews.

Answer (score 2):

Your starting point is https://www.drupal.org/project/projectapplications
You'll need to create an issue according to the instructions on this page. People will review (automated and manually) to check if this module is good for contrib.

Comment: how to get Git clone command for the sandbox .?

Comment: When you visit your sandbox page, it will have a tab 'Version control'. This will contain your GIT clone command. I think you just have to leave out your username. Ex: user@git.drupal: remove 'user@'.

Comment: There is a maintainer checkbox next to the version drop-down on the 'Versions control' page. This toggles the private and public git clone commands. (But is is basically removing the user@ part)

Answer (score 2):

To promote your sandbox project to full project, you will have to apply for permission to create a full project as described here in drupal docs: https://www.drupal.org/node/1011698 .

After getting permission you will be able to promote your sandbox to a full project.

Here are complete screenshots: https://www.drupal.org/node/1068952.

Answer (score 2):

As of 2017/03/07, users [do not need to go through the Project Application Review process](https://www.drupal.org/node/2666576) to promote a project.  With this change, people without the git-vetted status can promote one sandbox project to full project status.  See also the [change record](https://www.drupal.org/node/2856787):

> Strong signals about security advisory coverage are available on
>   project pages on Drupal.org, and in the updates.xml that is served by
>   Drupal.org for core to consume. There is also now a field for project
>   maintainers to opt into security advisory coverage.
>
> This means that we're now able to open the gates, to allow any user
>   who has accepted the Git repository usage policy to promote their
>   sandbox projects to full projects with releases.
>
> At the same time as we make this change, we'll be repurposing the
>   'git-vetted' user role as a 'may opt-into security coverage' role. The
>   existing project application process move from a gate on promoting
>   full projects to the gate for opting in to security advisory coverage.
>   That process will be further refined by various stakeholders in follow
>   ups.
>
> We'll be updating the documentation to reflect this change in process
>   as well.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach to "create a full project on drupal.org", is to investigate the existing (+17K) contributed modules, and narrow them down to projects with status like:

- [Seeking new maintainer](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module?f%5B0%5D=im_vid_44%3A9992&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=&f%5B3%5D=&f%5B4%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&text=&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc&op=Search) (685 hits).
- [Unsupported](https://www.drupal.org/project/project_module?f%5B0%5D=im_vid_44%3A13032&f%5B1%5D=&f%5B2%5D=&f%5B3%5D=&f%5B4%5D=sm_field_project_type%3Afull&text=&solrsort=iss_project_release_usage%20desc&op=Search) (1.524 hits).

From the search results that you get, verify if there is anything that has a "namespace" (= the machine name of your module) that might fit (or is close enough) to what your (new) module is about.

Then request the module's ownership to be treansfered, using these steps (in specified order):

1. Contact the module owner via the contact form of that owner on Drupal.org, asking for the ownership to be transferred.
2. If current owner indicates to agree with a transfer, or if after 2 weeks you have not received any response to step 1, then file an issue in 
   the [Drupal.org project ownership project](https://www.drupal.org/project/projectownership) (component = *Ownership transfer*), to request the "ownership to be transferred" (include relevant communication from step 1 to motivate your request). [Issue # 2367923](https://www.drupal.org/node/2367923) is an example of such issue.
3. The people handling the request from step 2 will then also try to contact the current owner (if you didn't get a reply to step 1.). And after a grace period of (about) 2 weeks, the project's ownership will be changed to you (unless there was some type of feedback from the current owner to not do so).
4. Do whatever you want to do with the module for which you became the new owner, without any review process involved. But make sure to:

   - give credit to the previous owner somehow.
   - NOT destroy any (GIT) history of the old version of the module.

The above period works fine, though it takes a little time (a few weeks at max) to complete all the steps ... And it has the advantage (I think) that you contribute a very little bit to reduce the amount of abonded-looking contributed modules.

**PS**: There are occasions where the current maintainer responds/reacts with something like "Hm, somebody interested in contributing to a 2nd live to a module I started ... how about I only grant co-maintainer status instead of transferring module ownership?". If that happens, then "you" have to decide if you yes/no are willing to accept that. A possible compromise in that case could be "how about we turn the table: I become owner, and make you (current owner) a co-maintainer".

Comment: This is great info. I wonder if it should be attached to a question specifically asking "Are there alternatives to applying for full project status?" instead of this one. If the question doesn't already exist, might not be a bad idea to create it. Just a thought.

Comment: Thanks for the kudos, you make me doubt if I should do so. I find it strange to answer my own question. I know you can do so, but it gives me the impression like "look how smart I am, in case you have a question like so, this is the answer to it" ... no? Maybe a question like "What are the pros and cons of taking over an existing contributed module?" is something I might consider (with a variation of my answer here ...).

Comment: :) I've thought about that, and have yet to do it myself. But when you ask a question there is a prompt right there that says, "Answer your own question – share your knowledge, Q&A-style". That seems rather encouraging, no? And there is also this: [Help Center: Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). It makes perfect sense to me, and with D8 on the horizon it would be great if more people would share in this way instead of waiting to be asked.

Comment: I just read it through. Had no idea it was such a sensitive thing, or that the PAR system is as broken as it is. No doubt the offer from kreynen to transfer projects to others didn't help (eep). On the up side, maybe the PAR admins have been given a little push to improve things. It would also be nice to see more effort behind cleaning up existing projects - maybe an Adopt-a-Project program. :) Where is this community wiki that it's been moved to? I'm not familiar with how that works.

Comment: @othermachines Thx for your feedback. About your "Adopt-a-Project": too late ... read my comments I added to the 2 newests answers there (i.e. the "Open Letter" link). About community wiki: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/community-wiki .. So all that's needed is that little checkbox bottom right if you create a new post. "I" did not ever mark my question (or answer) as such (a moderator did). PS: I just realized that about 40% of all my questions were converted to a wiki post also ... I try to understand "why" ...